# MobileFirst Quality Assurance Hybrid App Testing not Working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

I tried this tutorial to integrate MQA on my mobilefirst hybrid app:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/quality-assurance/7.1/hybrid/

On iOS I can see this in my logs:

```
 ERROR: Plugin 'MQAPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

I already added this on my config.xml also:

```
<feature name="MQAPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="MQAPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

Nothing is happening on my app, on android nothing is happening also I followed everything on that tutorial.

So I tried adding these codes on my App delegate for iOS and MQA was working, since the things that I've done for hybrid iOS is also applicable for native iOS, I just need to add these lines in my app delegate:

```
[[MQALogger settings] setMode:MQAModeQA];
[MQALogger startNewSessionWithApplicationKey:@"(my_ios_key)"];
```

Back to the error, why is it looking for a plugin? since I already added the Q4M.framework. For android also its looking for a plugin. What plug-in do I need to install? I need to make it work on my hybrid android project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you added the hybrid javascript, iPhone, and android SDK components found here? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27044490

You need to add those in eclipse, then add the native SDK in Xcode. Don't forget to re-build the eclipse project after you add the native SDK. The error should then go away in Xcode.

Comment: Yes, I added the 3 components.

Comment: Did you manually edit the config.xml file? That file will automatically be updated when you add the js, iPhone, and android components. After you add the components (make sure you are using version 3.0.18), add the reference to the MQA.js and tracekit.js files in index.html and add the MQA.startNewSession() function in the common > main.js file. Build and run as Xcode project. In Xcode, you add the native iOS sdk. Build in eclipse and run the project in Xcode. You don't need to add any native Obj-C code to get MQA working.